# Argument type does not conform to expected type MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm using this article as reference https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/
to build my app
I try to use matchingItem when searchBarText are equal then append to matchingItems.
I currently have a error message that
Argument type 'ServiceLocation' does not conform to expected type 'MKAnnotation'
which means I need to change the variable type for matchingItem.
I am not sure what is the best variable types when you want store ServiceLocation later for using as MapView.
Any Suggestion?

```
var matchingItems = [MKAnnotation]()
        var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil
    var allServiceLocations : [ServiceLocation] = []
        
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            
           
            matchingItems = []
            guard let mapView = mapView,
                let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            for location in allServiceLocations{
                if(location.locationName == searchBarText){
                   matchingItems.append(location)
                    
                }
            }
```

ServiceLocation.swift

```
struct ServiceLocation: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var locationType : LocationType
    var locationName: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var active: Bool
    var home : Bool
    var numAvailableChargers : Int
    var acronym : String?
    var eta: Int?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what the compiler is telling you is that you have an array of `MKAnnotation` but you're trying to stuff a `ServiceLocation` into it which is an unrelated type. As Swift is strongly typed, this is just invalid (thing square peg - round hole situation).

What you need to do is map your `ServiceLocation` to `MKAnnotation`, e.g. like so:

```
var matchingItems = [MKAnnotation]()
var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil
var allServiceLocations : [ServiceLocation] = []
        
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
      guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

        matchingItems = allServiceLocations.filter({ $0.locationName == searchBarText })
        .map({ 
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: $0.latitude)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: $0.longitude)!)
            annotation.title = $0.locationName
            annotation.subtitle = $0.locationType
        return annotation
       })
}
```

Comment: So I get 'MKAnnotation' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers on line   let annotation = MKAnnotation()

Comment: Apologies, been a while, see update (change to `MKPointAnnotation()`)

Comment: Thanks! so I add that it seem no error. I had already have file that search for subtitle and title and  want to append to matching for later purpose searching and zoom in to that location when user click in so do not want to return annotation.  github.com/williamkwon97/searchMapSwift here is my codes that search for CustomAnnotation from ServiceLocationViewController.swift could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: So I updated with your code and it's not just working same way as before. Do you how to modify  LocationSearchTable.swift ? Also there are multiplelocation List but I think this only for one location [link] (github.com/williamkwon97/searchMapSwift)

Comment: `So I updated with your code and it's not just working same way as before` can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: so I just put your codes (I think I need to modified something else too) but not sure what it is, but basically any of locations are not showing at all at this point

Comment: Did you keep the last `self.tableView.reloadData()` statement?

Comment: I did keep the last self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219307/discussion-between-anothercoder-and-zaitsman).

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. You could make `ServiceLocation` an annotation, by making it a `NSObject` subclass that conforms to `MKAnnotation`. So, first make it a class:

   ```
    class ServiceLocation: NSObject, Codable {
        var id: Int
        var locationType: LocationType
        var locationName: String
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
        var active: Bool
        var home: Bool
        var numAvailableChargers: Int
        var acronym: String?
        var eta: Int?

        init(id: Int, locationType: LocationType, locationName: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, active: Bool, home: Bool, numAvailableChargers: Int, acronym: String?, eta: Int?) {
            self.id = id
            self.locationType = locationType
            self.locationName = locationName
            self.latitude = latitude
            self.longitude = longitude
            self.active = active
            self.home = home
            self.numAvailableChargers = numAvailableChargers
            self.acronym = acronym
            self.eta = eta

            super.init()
        }
    }
   ```

   Second, add `MKAnnotation` protocol conformance with a few computed properties:

   ```
    extension ServiceLocation: MKAnnotation {
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) }
        var title: String? { locationName }
        var subtitle: String? { "\(numAvailableChargers) chargers" }
    }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could create an annotation class that has your original service location `struct` as a property:

   ```
    class ServiceLocationAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: serviceLocation.latitude, longitude: serviceLocation.longitude) }
        var title: String? { serviceLocation.locationName }
        var subtitle: String? { "\(serviceLocation.numAvailableChargers) chargers" }

        let serviceLocation: ServiceLocation

        init(serviceLocation: ServiceLocation) {
            self.serviceLocation = serviceLocation
            super.init()
        }
    }
   ```

   There are other permutations on this idea, but the key is to just make an annotation that has your `struct` as a property, and then, rather than adding the `ServiceLocation` to the map’s annotations, add a `ServiceLocationAnnotation`.

Obviously, make the subtitle whatever you want, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion! I am kinda new to still bit confuse where to put that haha. So I already have app that working for searching by "CustomAnnotation" but I need to use ServiceLocation title= locationName and subtitle should be an acronym and search by both. https://github.com/williamkwon97/searchMapSwift this is my github could you take a look at it and push it what you mean? sorry for extra work

Comment: Where to put it? Let’s imagine that you pursue the first example, you put `ServiceLocation` in your `ServiceLocation.swift` file, where you have it now, The only thing you’d need to add is an `import MapKit` at the start of the file. And you’re done.

Comment: so I got Use of undeclared type 'MKAnnotation' and Use of undeclared type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D  when I add to extension ServiceLocation: MKAnnotation

Comment: Did you do the `import MapKit`?

Comment: Hi, so I try second method to create class ServiceLocationAnnotation and basically create var allServiceLocations :  [ServiceLocationAnnotation] = [] then replace to  matchingItems = self.mapView!.allServiceLocations.filter  then I got Value of type 'MKMapView' has no member 'allServiceLocations'. I though ServiceLocationAnnotatio convert to annotation

Comment: Let me know if you have any ideas to fix this error